# Using Cursor in while Loop of a stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The problem is that,while loop is not working according to my expectation.i expecting this result...2018-05-01
2018-05-02
2018-05-03
2018-05-06
2018-05-07
2018-05-08
2018-05-09
2018-05-10
2018-05-13
2018-05-14
2018-05-15
2018-05-16
2018-05-17
2018-05-20
2018-05-21
2018-05-22
2018-05-23
2018-05-24
2018-05-27
2018-05-28
2018-05-29
2018-05-30
2018-05-31

```
  BEGIN
  declare varDay date;
  DECLARE v_finished INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE weekday VARCHAR(20);
  DECLARE weekend_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT weekendDay FROM weekend;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET  v_finished=1;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS daterange;
     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE daterange(
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      day DATE,
     PRIMARY KEY(id)
      ); 



    WHILE(sdate <= enddate) DO
     OPEN weekend_cursor;
     get_weekend:LOOP
       FETCH weekend_cursor INTO weekday;
        IF v_finished =1 THEN 
         CLOSE weekend_cursor;  
          LEAVE get_weekend;

          ELSEIF DAYNAME(sdate)!=weekday THEN
           INSERT INTO daterange (day) values (sdate);
          END IF;
        END LOOP  get_weekend;


    SET sdate = DATE_ADD(sdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    SET varDay = sdate;
   END WHILE;

   SELECT * FROM daterange;
   END
```

Comment: What does your create statement look like and what does your call statement look like?

Comment: create statement creates a temp table that holds date generates by while loop between date range  without weekends,Friday and Saturday.Call proc('2018-05-01','2018-05-31');

Comment: To make this work you would need an outer loop to increment sdate and an inner loop to loop through the cursor but I don't see why you would need the cursor at all since the mysql function dayname function would identify friday or saturday anyway,

Comment: I want to remove the friday and saturday from my date table and friday and saturday will come from database.One more thing i am using while loop to increment sdate.